# Match part of string with part of other string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I working on a simple search function where I want to match a part of a string with part of another string.

Example:
The search term is: fruitbag
I want to match the product: fruit applebag

I want to create something so that the system matches:

- **fruit**bag
- **fruit** applebag

Or even "fruit" and "bag".

In summary; parts inside a string need to match with parts inside the search term. Is this possible?

```
    $products = array(
        'fruit applebag',
        'pinapple',
        'carrots',
        'bananas',
        'coconut oil',
        'cabbage',
    );

    if( ! empty( $_POST['search'] ) ) {

        $s = $_POST['search'];
        $results = array();
        foreach( $products as $index => $product ) {

            if( preg_match( '/' . $s . '.*/i', $product, $matched ) ) {
                $results[] = $matched[0];
            }
        }
        print_r($results); 
        // This only returns fruit applebag if the search term is something like "fruit ap"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this (split the searched word into two parts and look for a match thas has characters between those two parts):

```
$products = array(
        'fruit applebag',
        'pinapple',
        'carrots',
        'bananas',
        'coconut oil',
        'cabbage',
    );
$s = 'fruitbag';
$results = array();
foreach( $products as $index => $product ) {
    for($i=1;$i<strlen($s);$i++){
        if(preg_match( '/' . substr($s,0,$i) . '.*'.substr($s,$i+1).'/i', $product, $matched ) ) {
            $results[] = $matched[0];
        }
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => fruit applebag [1] => fruit applebag )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, but as Eric Leibenguth says, it now matches almost every character. So I think I need to add a minimum of characters on it like 3 or 4..

Comment: sure, but my solution is for that double match as in `fruit.*bag`. The solution for single match is easy, you can just add conditional statement for `strlen` value.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but could be very costly. As stated, your requirement is that any substring of the search term is potentially relevant. So take `fruitbag` and generate a list of all substrings:

```
f,r,u,i,t,b,a,g,fr,ru,ui,it,tb,ba,ag,fru,rui,uit,...,bag,...,fruit,...,fruitbag
```

But you probably don't want that any word with the letter `a` be a match. So a first approach could be to specify a minimum number of letters (e.g. 3), which will significantly limit the potential matches. But even then... Does it make sense to match `fru`, or `rui`?

A better approach would be to use a dictionary, to extract actual words or syllables from your search string. (In your case, extract `fruit` and `bag` from `fruitbag`).

You can find an English dictionary [fairly easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741003/a-text-file-with-a-list-of-words).